# Apache Tomcat 7 domain issue proxy settings

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, dns, favicon

My first post in this site, I haven't read the terms and conditions upon entry so sorry if I violate the rules or anything.......

The problem I am having is that I am trying to familiarise myself with website hosting. I have downloaded `apache-tomcat-7.0.59-`.

I put a `Index.html` and a `favicon`. I followed another tutorial online and I have done this correctly into the `webapps` root directory.

Now, when I type in `localhost:8080` and public `ip address:8080` *Everything is beautiful and perfect!* and I can see my website with my favicon.

The **problem happens** when I put `www.mydomain.com`
(which is what I purchased and forwarded to my public router ip address and port 8080)

**The index is there! but why not my favicon ??** I opened in **tor**, **internet explorer** and also **firefox** but **still no favicon**! and this isn't my only problem.

I am also hosting a webapp called *cyclos* that uses Java. *It goes wiered* when I put `www.mydomain.com` but *it works perfectly* when I put `http://localhost:8080` and when I put `my publicip:8080` ?

Sorry for the damn long reply, but this issue has taken me about 7 days to fix and I am waiting for somebody to kindly help me but please keep in mind that I am a complete NOOB when it comes to this high tech stuff so please explain it to me like a 5 year old boy

Comment: Check for file permission for the favicon ?

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the page (F5), or remove browser cache before accessing from public domain?

Comment: Are you just putting your favicon.ico file in the webapp root folder or specifing with <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>?

Comment: I have refreshed and deleted my browser cache, and I did specify the link and everything. I followed many different types of tutorials online. I am pretty sure the problem is the domain and proxy settings. www.mydomain.com Doesn't work!  but localhost:8080 and Publicip:8080 works

Comment: if you put in a browser www.yourdomain.com/favicon.ico what's shown?

Comment: When I put it in internet explorer nothing happens. But when I put it in firefox and tor I can see my favicon. When I type my full url it still doesn't work. I find this very strange.......